# Automatically Fixing File System Errors

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, filesystems, smart

[image]
This problem is related to my WD External HDD.
It has developed File System Errors. I found that out when I saw that the HDD is taking unusually long time to read the data and whenever I try to open a file or folder, explorer.exe crashes.
I checked the SMART status of the drive using GSMartControl and it says that SMART status is OK.
So , is it safe to use the in-built method to recover the FS or should I use some external tool?
Also, I dont want to lose data. Please help!

[image]
I tried defragging the HDD and that is what I get: stuck on 63%

Comment: If you fear have fear to lost the data I think `chkdsk /f` would help you a lot in that condition. But if doesn't fix the problem then you can use other methods.

Comment: I wanna avoid losing data. But if it the last resort, then be it. Simplest way being formatting the drive

Comment: `Chkdsk /f` will work like a charm as it did for most of the user's as it don't lost the data, and also you can try to defrag the disk. Also there are many tools to recover the lost data.

Comment: it gets stuck at stage 2 of 3

Comment: Do you checking whole HDD at once or by each partition. Sometime it take too long time to fix the errors on HDD depends on the condition of partitions sectors. Be cool and wait for its response if have any problem post the screen shot with an edit of the post.

Comment: Check. I have posted the snap shot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4569/discussion-between-avirk-and-fasih-khatib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good place to start with is a drive test.  There are a variety of bootable disk utilities to test the health of Hard Drives. One simple but effective tool I like to use is [Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hgst.com/support/index-files/simpletech-legacy-downloads#DFT). This will tool will essentially go through the drive checking for bad sectors as well as performing a number of other checks in the process.

If DFT reports that the drive is failing (diagnostics in red box) you should check to see if the drive is still under warranty and if possible file an RMA claim to get it replaced.

If it does not report any problems (green ok) then you don't need to worry for the time being about Hard Drive health and should look elsewhere for the problem.